# AngularJS pagination in separate columns

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I have pagination working in my app. I display 10 elements per page. Now I would like to format these 10 elements into 2 columns (2x 5 elements per 1 page).

I don't know how to start.

```
<pagination data-boundary-links="true" data-num-pages="noOfPages" data-current-page="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-small" data-previous-text="&laquo;" data-next-text="&raquo;"></pagination>
```

Code reference:

http://jsfiddle.net/eqCWL/224/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle you are using the older bootstrap2 css, so I'll use it here for the solution:

First, you need to read the [bootstrap documentation on scaffolding/grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem)

format your HTML to show two lists in two rows:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6">
      <li>{{data.name}}</li>
  </div>
  <div class="span6">
      <li>{{data.name}}</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

then, you will need to set the first ng-repeat to show only half of items:

```
ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search) | 
startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit/2"
```

notice `limitTo:entryLimit/2`
and the second one to show the rest:

```
ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search) | 
startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit + entryLimit/2 | limitTo:entryLimit/2"
```

you need to change the `startFrom` filter, to start `entryLimit / 2` items later:

```
startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit + entryLimit/2
```

You can test a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gysp5eeh/)